# dynamic css classes in vue

Tags: css, vue.js, tailwind-css

I'm creating a component using vuejs and tailwindcss. I'm encountering an issue where the background and text colors are not applied.

```
<template>
  <div :class="[isDark ? `bg-${color}-900 text-white` : `bg-${color}-200 text-${color}-900`, 'p-4 rounded-md']">
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "TCard",
  props: {
    color: {
      type: String,
      default: "gray",
      validator: function (value) {
        return ["gray", "red", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "purple", "pink"].includes(value);
      },
    },
    isDark: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could consider using a map of classes instead like:

```js
const MAP = {
  gray: {
    light: 'bg-gray-200 text-gray-900',
    dark: 'bg-gray-900 text-white',
  },
  red: {
    light: 'bg-red-200 text-red-900',
    dark: 'bg-red-900 text-white',
  },
  // …
};

const TCard = {
  props: {
    color: {
      type: String,
      default: "gray",
      validator: function (value) {
        return value in MAP;
      },
    },
    isDark: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    colors() {
      return MAP[this.color][this.isDark ? 'dark' : 'light'];
    },
  },
  template: `
<div :class="[colors, 'p-4 rounded-md']">
  <slot />
</div>`
};

Vue.createApp({ components: { TCard }}).mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.3.4/vue.global.min.js" integrity="sha512-Wbf9QOX8TxnLykSrNGmAc5mDntbpyXjOw9zgnKql3DgQ7Iyr5TCSPWpvpwDuo+jikYoSNMD9tRRH854VfPpL9A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div id="app">
  <t-card color="red">Foo</t-card>
  <t-card color="gray" is-dark>Bar</t-card>
</div>
```

This keeps the classes you use and the template markup together. The `validator` can also use the `MAP` to verify a color you want to use exists.

Otherwise, you could use [`safelist`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes) in your Tailwind configuration like:

```js
module.exports = {
  …
  safelist: [
    { pattern: /^(bg|text)-(gray|red|yellow|green|blue|indigo|purple|pink)-900$/ },
    { pattern: /^bg-(gray|red|yellow|green|blue|indigo|purple|pink)-200$/ },
  ],
  …
};
```

This has the disadvantage that this would be separate from your templates so you might lose/forget the link these two have. This would mean maintaining this would be more difficult to keep in sync and editing this would mean a context switch too.